# I try to run localhost Django for Webdevelopment but this error happen How can I solve it

Tags: python, html, django, web, pip

```
You have 17 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you  
apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.  
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.  
March 14, 2021 - 13:57:58
Django version 3.0, using settings 'firstweb.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
**Error: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a   
way forbidden by its access permissions**
```

Answer (score 0):

i've had this problem and tried the next.

first try just restarting the computer (always a good thing), and then run your terminal or prompt as administrator.

if that donest work try changing the port like : python manage.py runserver 8080, because aperantly the port 8000 is being used by something else,

that did the trick for me, hope it can help.